Black hole event horison diameter to steller mass
are event horizon diameters linear as compared to stellar mass? it seems as if there were singularities involved billion star mass black holes would have a relatively smaller event horizon diameter than a 100 solar mass black hole
sorry for being vague.if i understand our sun would make a black hole of about 6 km  would a 1 billion stellar mass black hole be 1 billion times the diameter ? if so what does this say about singularities?
As explained by James in the comments the diameter of a black hole expands linearly as mass is added. this leads me to ask why cant  the apparent diameter compared to the actual diameter be used to judge the distance to the black hole?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Area of event horizon is $A \propto m^2$, while at the same time $A \propto r^2$. This means $r \propto m$, so the diameter ($2r$) of an event horizon grows linearly as mass is added into it.

It sounds like you refer to some idea of how the singularity may affect the horizon, but you give no explanation and people cannot read your mind. Perhaps the best way to start on black holes is by learning how to express your thoughts clearly with proper grammar and punctuation.

So for a non-spinning neutral Blackhole, there is one parameter: mass ($M$), with dimensions $[M]$.
From that, we need to make a radius, $R$, with dimensions $[L]$.
We have at our disposal, the fundamental constants: $G$, $c$, $\hbar$, $k$.
The usual way to proceed is to throw out quantum mechanics (no $\hbar$), and say it's not a thermodynamics problem (no $k$) and then match dimensions using $G$ and $c$...this should tell you $R \propto M$, but I am going to skip that step and just say:
$$ \frac{R_S}{l_P} \propto \frac{M}{m_p} $$
where the Planck length and Planck mass are, respectively:
$$ l_P = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}} \approx 1.6\times 10^{-35}\,{\rm m} $$
$$ m_P = \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G c}G} \approx 2.2\times 10^{-8}\,{\rm kg} $$
so the fundamental scaling between mass and length is:
$$\frac{l_P}{m_p} = \frac{\sqrt{\frac{\hbar G}{c^3}}}{ \sqrt{\frac{\hbar G c}G}} $$
$$\frac{l_P}{m_p} =  \sqrt{\frac{G^2}{c^4}}
$$
$$\frac{l_P}{m_p} =  \frac G{c^2} \approx 7.3\times 10^{-28}
\,{\rm m/kg}
$$
Anyway, puting that all together:
$$ R_S \propto \frac G {c^2} M $$
where the constant of proportionality is $2$.
So if your question is about relative size of an object $(R)$ vs. its Schwarzschild radius, then the parameter:
$$ R/R_S$$
depends on the object, and as that approaches $1$, you need to use general realtivity.
In actual applications, parameterized post-Newtonian formalism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parameterized_post-Newtonian_formalism) is used, and it has more sophisticated parameters. Nonetheless, it's similar to post-Minkowski formalism, where $v/c\rightarrow 1$ indicate the need to include special realtivity.

The question seems to assume the asker is completely familiar with dimensional analysis and why it's a valid way to solve problems, which I sincerely doubt. Also (as you pointed out) there was no reason to involve hbar, but you did anyway, potentially making the argument insufficient.  $R_s/l_p\sim M/m_p$ is stated without proof, and within dimensional analysis, is not a valid argument. $R_s/l_p\sim M^2/m_p^2$ would also be dimensionally valid. So actually you'll notice that if you include hbar in your list of fundamental constants, dimensional analysis does not give a unique answer.

@AXensen yeah, but I already concluded it was linear in M based on the dimensional analysis I didn't do. I get that without that it could be $\cos{M/m_p}$ or worse.

I mean, this is better than the argument I would've made by quite a bit. I simply would've stated that $r_s=2GMc^{-2}=kM$ and called it a day. It shows clear effort and, if I understand the question correctly, is the fundamentally-right answer, and gets there in a more or less coherent way.
